# How can I create permutations of sub trees from the parsing tree?

Tags: java, scala, stanford-nlp

I am trying to split up sentence like this; For example:

> "*I ate here a week ago and found most dishes average at best and too expensive but the waitress was really nice.*"

is supposed to become

> "*I ate here a week ago and found most dishes average at best.*"
>   "*I ate here a week ago and found most dishes too expensive.*"
>   "*I ate here a week ago and the waitress was really nice.*"

Essentially I am having all information I need form the Stanfort Parser(s)

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse")
```

but the problem is that I have troubles with the API. Looking at the sentence below what I basically need is some sort of permutations algorithm depending on conditions like "is the subtree connected via `amod` relation or not; If *yes* we can permutate conjunctions as in

> "*.. average at best and too expensive ..*"

Could somebody help me to accomplish that? All my attempts ended somewhat at "*Okay, and how do I now get `.get(<annotation-type>.class)`?*" or something similar. `Scala` (preferred) and/or `Java` would be okay.

[image]

[image]

---

My latest try looks like this:

```scala
for(iw <- allWords) {

  println(iw.get(classOf[TextAnnotation]))
  val out = semanticGraph.getOutEdgesSorted(iw)

  for(edge <- out) {

    if(edge.getRelation.getShortName.startsWith("amod")) {

      val tree = edge.getTarget.get(classOf[TreeAnnotation])
      val lbl = new CoreLabel()
      val treeGraphNodes = new TreeGraphNode(lbl, tree.getChildrenAsList)
      val relNodes = edge.getRelation.getRelatedNodes(treeGraphNodes, treeGraphNodes, null)

      println("")
    }
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to get all affected nodes from the `amod` relation as can be seen in the top picture. It should return the related nodes but since `tree` is always `null` it cannot be done this way I am afraid.

Comment: Maybe you should first try and isolate the subtrees you are interested in?

Comment: @fge Well, I'd need to know how.. I know what needs to be done but the API is against me. I try to build a `TreeGraphNode` at the moment but not even that seems to work out for me..

Comment: Maybe you can perform a postorder traversal and isolate what you want? If you use Java 8 you may be interested in [this](https://github.com/JavaChat/streems)

Comment: @fge I think you're getting me wrong here .. it's it now that I don't know what I *have* to do.. it's that I don't know *how* to do it. I know that CoreNLP delivers all I need but I'm not able to accomplish my target.